# How to know if SmtpClient is ready to send an email

Tags: c#, email

In C#, if you try to send an email with `SendAsync` before the previous one has completed, this exception is raised:

> An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.

It makes sense, but I cannot find a property like `IsBusy` to check whether the client is ready to accept a new send request. I might just try and handle the exception, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

### UPDATE

I'm trying with `SendMailAsync`:

```
public async Task SendEmail(string address, string subject, string body, Attachment attachment)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(m_smtp.username);
    mail.To.Add(address);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    if (attachment != null)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    await m_smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);
    Console.WriteLine("Send completed!");
}
```

This raises the following exception (but the debugger doesn't break the execution):

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in mscorlib.dll
Failure sending mail.
System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading.
at System.Net.Mime.MimeBasePart.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMessageCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

If I only change `SendMailAsync()` with `Send()` the email is sent successfully.

Comment: You shouldn't use `SendAsync` these days. Use `SendMailAsync`. That returns a task that you should `await`. Or if async code is too tricky, send it synchronously. If you insist on using `SendAsync`, there is [an event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) that fires when sending is complete.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the exception. What is the message, inner exception etc.

Comment: That's all appears in the output window (debug mode). No inner exception appears. That's weird.

Comment: Then *catch* the exception and *log* it.